# Multiple returns in python in a function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently trying to make a function where it returns multiple return outputs in a single function. I'll add an example of what I'm trying to achieve below.

```
def verify(self, isRound: bool = None, isColored: bool = None, isBounce: bool = None):
    if isRound:  # When 'isRound' is True
        return "Object is round"

    if not isRound:  # When 'isRound' is False
        return "Object is not round"
   
    if isColored:  # When 'isColored' is True
        return "Object is colored"

    if not isColored:  # When 'isColored' is False
        return "Object is not colored"
    
    if isBounce:  # When 'isBounce' is True
        return "Object bounces"

    if not isBounce:  # When 'isBounce' is False
        return "Object doesnt bounce"
```

Input:
`verify(isRound = True, isColored = False)`

Output:

"Object is round"

"Object is not colored"

Comment: Just a quick note: If you define inside a class you call it method not function. Since you have self, as first parameter of your function I guess you mean a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return, the function returns control to the upper code. You better make a list and return it at the end.

```
def verify(self, isRound: bool = None, isColored: bool = None, isBounce: bool = None):

    res = []  # To return at end

    if isRound:  # When 'isRound' is True
        res.append("Object is round")

    if not isRound:  # When 'isRound' is False
        res.append("Object is not round")
   
    if isColored:  # When 'isColored' is True
        res.append("Object is colored")

    if not isColored:  # When 'isColored' is False
        res.append("Object is not colored")
    
    if isBounce:  # When 'isBounce' is True
        res.append("Object bounces")

    if not isBounce:  # When 'isBounce' is False
        res.append("Object doesnt bounce")

    return res
```

Also you can make it more readable with some changes:

```
def verify(self, isRound: bool = None, isColored: bool = None, isBounce: bool = None):

    res = []  # To return at end

    res.append("Object is round" if isRound else "Object is not round")
    res.append("Object is colored" if isColored else "Object is not colored")
    res.append("Object bounces" if isBounce else "Object doesnt bounce")

    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways, here are 2:

First (output multiple values):

```
def verify(self, isRound: bool = None, isColored: bool = None, isBounce: bool = None):
    
    dict_output = {}
    
    if isRound:
        out_round = "Object is round"
    else:
        out_round = "Object is not round"

    if isColored:
        out_isColored = "Object is colored"
    else:
        out_isColored = "Object is not colored"

    if isBounce:
        out_isBounce = "Object bounces"
    else:
        out_isBounce = "Object doesnt bounce"

    return out_round, out_isColored, out_isBounce

a, b, c = verify()
```

Second (output an iterable like a list or dictionary):

```
def verify(self, isRound: bool = None, isColored: bool = None, isBounce: bool = None):
    
    dict_output = {}
    
    if isRound:
        dict_output["out_round"] = "Object is round"
    else:
        dict_output["out_round"] = "Object is not round"

    if isColored:
        dict_output["out_isColored"] = "Object is colored"
    else:
        dict_output["out_isColored"] = "Object is not colored"

    if isBounce:
        dict_output["out_isBounce"] = "Object bounces"
    else:
        dict_output["out_isBounce"] = "Object doesnt bounce"

    return dict_output

dict_verify = verify()
print(dict_verify.get("out_round"))
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the "self" argument from the definition of the function. we dont need self when defining functions. and replace "return" with print in all the if statements.

like this:

```
def verify(isRound: bool = None, isColored: bool = None, isBounce: bool = None):
    if isRound:  # When 'isRound' is True
        print("Object is round")

    if not isRound:  # When 'isRound' is False
        print("Object is not round")
```